# Umbraco Option to define dropdown list via Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I am facing an issue using Umbraco 7.0. My requirement is that I need to create a contact us form page and from that page an email will be sent to admin. I thought of creating .Net User Control for achieving
this functionality. 
However, in Contact Us page, there is a field like "Functional Area" that client wants a drop down and in that he wants, Option to define drop down list via Umbraco.

Could anyone please guide me how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the old User Control method, you would be better off writing one using Razor which can use a Model populated with content. There is a nice example here of something very similar that you can extend

http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2012/5/24/creating-an-umbraco-form-using-pure-razor.aspx